# Efficient Data Processing for Large Datasets in Apache Airflow ETL

Tags: python, dataframe, airflow, etl

I am currently working on my thesis, which involves building an ETL pipeline using Apache Airflow. I have been using Pandas for data processing, but it fails to efficiently handle large datasets (65 million+ rows) and take a lot of time to fetch from db (Oracle), process and load data. I have tried other libraries like Modin and some distributed DataFrame libraries, but I encountered an issue with Airflow and these libraries competing for the same CPU resources (similar to the multiprocessing module).

My question is: What do data engineers commonly use for building efficient ETL pipelines within Apache Airflow, especially when dealing with large datasets?

P.S. I have also experimented with PySpark, but it didn't provide significant performance improvements in my case. Any suggestions or recommendations are highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!